# libcamera-vid fails to operate in higher resolution

Tags: camera, libcamera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye-64

I try to run *libcamera-vid* with several camera modules at higher resolutions, but fail. Calling *libcamera-still* works as expected.

The behavior can be reproduced with several modules with OmniVision 5647, Sony IMX219 and IMX519 sensors. Trouble starts at 2592×1944. Image file can be generated, video cannot be started.

For example, using an IMX219 module, the command `libcamera-vid -v -n --width 3280 --height 2464 --output -` does not give any output and terminates immediately after being called:

```
[0:24:20.369130982] [1186]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:299 libcamera v0.0.4+22-923f5d70
[0:24:20.500309865] [1187]  WARN RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1357 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:24:20.504227416] [1187]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1476 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
Acquired camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10
Configuring video...
[0:24:20.507309968] [1186]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1028 configuring streams: (0) 3280x2464-YUV420
[0:24:20.508741634] [1187]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:851 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 - Selected sensor format: 3280x2464-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 3280x2464-pBAA
Camera streams configured
Available controls:
```

[...]

```
Buffers allocated and mapped
Video setup complete
Opened H264Encoder on /dev/video11 as fd 24
Got 6 output buffers
Got 12 capture buffers
Closing Libcamera application(frames displayed 0, dropped 0)
Camera stopped!
Tearing down requests, buffers and configuration
Camera closed
ERROR: *** failed to start output streaming ***
```

Other resolutions up to 1920×1080 work fine, but 3280×2464 should be possible, no?

```
$ libcamera-vid --list-cameras
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : imx219 [3280x2464] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10)
    Modes: 'SRGGB10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [103.33 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                             1640x1232 [41.85 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                             1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                             3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
           'SRGGB8' : 640x480 [103.33 fps - (1000, 752)/1280x960 crop]
                      1640x1232 [41.85 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
                      1920x1080 [47.57 fps - (680, 692)/1920x1080 crop]
                      3280x2464 [21.19 fps - (0, 0)/3280x2464 crop]
```

The camera is recognized at startup with a warning (which shows up for other image sensors as well):

```
$ dmesg | grep imx
[    0.115807] platform 3f801000.csi: Fixed dependency cycle(s) with /soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10
[   13.467359] imx219 10-0010: Consider updating driver imx219 to match on endpoints
```

I also tried to put

```
bcm2835-v4l2
# enable higher-resolution video
options bcm2835-v4l2 max_video_width=3240 max_video_height=2464
```

to `/etc/modules-load.d/rpi-camera.conf` as suggested
[here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AlpineLinux/comments/u3gv4z/how_to_enable_raspberry_pi_camera_module/), but without any noticeable change.

However, `libcamera-still -n --width 3280 --height 2464 -n -o /tmp/foo.bar` gives the expected JPEG image file with full resolution.

OS: Raspberry Pi OS bullseye 64bit lite, Raspi 3B, libcamera-apps-lite version git20230301+54a781d, libcamera0 version git20230302+923f5d70-1.